# Change Expand/Collapse icon in wxDataViewCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to replace the Expand/Collapse icon with my icons in wxDataViewCtrl.

[image]

I am not able to find a way to set my expand/collapse icons.
Is there any API available for the same?

or

Do I need to modify the wxDataViewCtrl source directly? your prior experience can help me.

Answer (score 2):

The main point of having `wxDataViewCtrl` in the first place is that it wraps the corresponding native control, so changing its look and feel is not supported.

This being said, if you're using its generic implementation, as is always the case under MSW, you can actually change it by defining a custom [wxRendererNative](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_renderer_native.html)-derived class and overriding its `DrawTreeItemButton()` method. But this would affect all the other controls drawing tree-like buttons, including, obviously, generic `wxTreeCtrl` itself but also `wxPropGrid`. Generally speaking I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: What can I do, I have no choice. Actually I need to customize other native drawings too. like Scrollbar, Expand/Collapse icon, wxDataViewCtrl default system row selection color, Combobox arrow icon and many more.

Comment: Maybe wxWidgets is not the right choice then. It puts native appearance first and customizability second, while it seems that for you it's the other way round.

Comment: How can I use generic implementation on Mac

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it is right approach or wrong, Here I found a way to achieve my thing based on VZ.suggestion.

```
class MyRenderer : public wxDelegateRendererNative
{
public:
    MyRenderer() : wxDelegateRendererNative(wxRendererNative::GetDefault()) { }

    virtual void DrawTreeItemButton(wxWindow *win,
        wxDC& dc,
        const wxRect& rect,
        int flags = 0)
    {
        MyCustomCtrl* pWin = dynamic_cast<MyCustomCtrl*>(win->GetParent());
        if (pWin != nullptr)
        {
            // Draw my choice of expand/collapse button.
        }
        else
        {   // Do not affect other controls that are using this drawing.
            wxRendererNative::GetDefault().DrawTreeItemButton(win, dc, rect, flags);
        }
    }
};
```

This way I can override the

```
virtual void DrawItemSelectionRect(wxWindow *win,
        wxDC& dc,
        const wxRect& rect,
        int flags)
```

and many more native drawings.